# how to make a scroll with TextField dynamically

Tags: swift, swift3

how to make a scroll with TextField dynamically, with a button ADD , and if the number of textView it's too big, i can move the scroll and check it.

And no matter how many each text view is placed below that of the top?

Sample:-

[image]

Comment: Try to use [`Vertical stack view`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html)

Comment: Hi, sorry I made a mistake. I meant textfield and not textview. I can not understand how it is possible to generate textfield to infinity in the scroll.

Comment: When you add `uitextfield` in scrollview, then update the `content size` of your scroll view programatically.

Comment: Ok thanks you, I will look in this direction

Comment: Thanks you it's running

Comment: Shall I post it as an answer?

Comment: adjust the Scroll when the UITextField out of the aera and adjust the size : ScrollView.contentSize.height = height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to take this opportunity to [add my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934888/how-to-make-a-scroll-with-textfield-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment71065511_41934888) as an answer, so that it can reach to maximum users thus helping them.

When you add UITextField(or any other UI element) in `UIScrollView`, then update the `content size` of your scroll view programatically.